# Seeking help for a simple Interval Alarm (Pi Zero)

Tags: audio, pi-zero

I recently found myself in possession of a Raspberry Pi Zero. I've never had a chance to play around with one before, and so I was just after a bit of guidance on how to go about a certain project.

I usually find myself sitting at my desk for way too long while working, and I figured that a good healthy use for the Pi would be an unobtrusive single-beep alarm that went off every hour to remind myself to stand up and walk around a little.

And that's it! I guess it's a pretty simple project, but honestly I'm pretty lost as to how I would begin to go about it. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here... and by all means could you please edit the title of the question to be meaningful and related to the specific question?

Comment: One thing not addressed in your question or answer is that you will get up and move for some minutes once the alarm goes off. If you run this to go off every hour the length of time you are sitting before an alarm is reduced. For example if you plan to move around for 10 minutes and the alarm starts at 1PM thefirst alarm goes off at 2PM. After walking for 10 min. you sit back down at 2:10pm and the alarm goes off at 3PM (only 50 minutes). How do you account for the time when you actually get up during the hour should the alarm still go off at the top of the next hour?

Comment: I am not saying this is impossible - it isn't but it is not completely thought out either.

Comment: Hi Steve - That lost time would just be part of the hour. It would just go something like [5 minutes standing] -> [55 minutes sitting]. So going off exactly every hour would be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a cron job to execute a script every hour.
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md

Then you need to work out how to make the noise ... perhaps a sound card or a PWM through a piezo sensor ?

Comment: Thanks Matt. Definitely seems like cron job + piezo speaker is the way to go.